# Groovy sort works in Grails unit test but not on server

Tags: grails, groovy

I am doing a small sort in a Grails controller like so:

```
itemList.sort { a, b ->
            Integer num1 = a.identifier as Integer
            Integer num2 = b.identifier as Integer
            num1 <=> num2
        }
```

The identifier on the List objects is a String, so I am doing the conversion so they are sorted as Integers. I have unit tests that verify this sort is working correctly without a doubt, however, when I deploy this application to a server the sort doesn't work at all.

I am using Grails 2.2.1. I'm out of ideas…any leads I can explore?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have example data that doesn't work? Can you print it out on the server to see what it's sorting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim - I'm using a dataset in my unit tests that mirrors the "problem" set on the server. I will add some logging to see if that helps. Having a hard time deciding where this issue could originate since my language/framework versions shouldn't be the issue. I was wondering if anyone else had maybe seen inconsistencies like this between the prod and test environments in Grails possibly.

Comment: After the sort are you working with itemList or the return value of sort()?  The Groovy JDK states for [Collections.sort()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) that if itemList isn't a List (e.g., a Set) itemList won't be sorted, but the return value will be.  In a unit test versus production itemList might also be different datatypes.

Comment: I think that sort(Closure) method that you're using normally *returns* a sorted copy of the list, but shouldn't be expected to modify the itemList on which sort is called.  You may be creating a sorted list and dropping it on the floor, and maybe it's just a weird side-effect that it got sorted at all in the unit test.  I agree with schmolli, that there's likely a difference in backing list types causing this difference.

Comment: @schmolli I missed that - I'll look into that further. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnFlinchbaugh I was making an assumption on sort, I'll make sure I'm using it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @schmolli you were right on - if you make that an answer I'll accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are working with the return value from the sort() call and not the original collection. The Groovy JDK states for [Collection.sort(Closure)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) that if the original collection isn't a List (e.g., a Set) it won't be sorted, but the return value will be. In a unit test versus production the original collection might also be different datatypes.